# access object properties from a multidimensional array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, object, multidimensional-array, properties

I am new to Objective-C programming and I am trying to access object properties from a 2 dimensional array.
First I created two arrays, each of those arrays contains objects, then I made a 2 dimensional array that contains those arrays of objects by using NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *team1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[team1 addObject:tank1];
[team1 addObject:btr1];
[team1 addObject:ambulance1];

NSMutableArray *team2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[team2 addObject:tank2];
[team2 addObject:btr2];
[team2 addObject:ambulance2];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

[array addObject:team1];
[array addObject:team2];
```

What I want to do now is to access the properties of these objects by referring them from my 2d array and print them by using NSLog. Is this possible? 
Please excuse me my question looks complicated, this is something new for me.

Comment: Do you know how to access an element in a one dimensional array? Do it twice. I would use a dictionary instead of the second array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the above reference code to access the object like this.

**1. To access  btr 1**

index for this will be : item 0, object 1 for array  so can access by this code.

```
[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]
```

**2. To access  ambulance2**

index for this will be : item 0, object 1 for array  so can access by this code.

```
[[array objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:2]
```

3. You can print them with same code given here as

   NSlog(Item at object: %d index of 'array' and item in 'array' at index : %d is == %@,outerarray(array) index, innerarray(item array) index, [[array objectAtIndex:outerarrayindex] objectAtIndex:innerarrayindex]);

Or simply `NSlog(@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:outerarrayindex] objectAtIndex:innerarrayindex]);`

Comment: Thank you for your response @vicky ! !.  But my problem was to acces not the objects of the array, but the properties of these objects. As I found out later I should use       '((ObjectName *)array[i][j]).property'  to acces the property of the object at position [i][j].